# BSC always return insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: ether, bsc, web3.php

I want to send a transaction in BSC network.
I already set this params for sending

```
Array
(
    [nonce] => 0
    [address] => 0xb7a2565fa170b8b5b2bf5035665f169066a5c7fb
    [toaddress] => 0xF355320a7d4F2aF95a43C64CD2e76bBE266286Aa
    [gaslimit] => 21000
    [gasprice] => 5
    [value_wei] => 0.01
    [web3ChainId] => 97
)
```

which is calles from this code

```
    $transactionparams = array(
      "nonce" => $gettransactioncount,
      'address' => $address,
      'toaddress' => $toaddress,
      'gaslimit' => 21000,
      'gasprice' => 5,
      'value_wei' => 0.01,
      'web3ChainId' => 0x61
    );
```

Then I try to send it to BSC network and set these params

```
function bcdechex($dec){
    $hex = '';
    do {
        $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
        $hex = dechex($last) . $hex;
        $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
    } while ($dec > 0);
    return $hex;
}

    $transactionParams = [
        'nonce' => "0x" . dechex($nonce),
        'from' => strtolower($address),
        'to' =>  strtolower($toaddress),
        'gasLimit' =>  '0x' . dechex($gaslimit),
        'gasPrice' =>  '0x' . hexdec(dechex($gasprice)),
        'value' => '0x' . bcdechex($value_wei),
        'chainId' => strval($web3ChainId)
    ];
```

but always return insufficient funds for gas * price + value
I already try to reduce the amount of sending also try to increase the gas price and limit but no luck. Anyone know this?

Comment: Do you allow spend of your token ? "Approve" , toAddress need have function check the smart contract and for buy token its a path [tokenA,tokenB], your address 0xF355320a7d4F2aF95a43C64CD2e76bBE266286Aa don't have function this is not a smart contract

Comment: I'm not saying that I send a token from smart contract? By the way I already found the solution thanks

Comment: Ok cool if you find solution can you please add it for other please its important for this community here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a fix
change the request to a higher gasprice since the last previous transac will be replace by it

```
Array
(
    [gasprice] => 10
)
```